# Cement exterior pool wall

Tags: walls

I'm going to try and help my parents fix a few things but I'm trying to figure out how to get this wall back straight. The problem is actually the downspout pouring water directly next to the edge of this wall. That's an easy rerouting fix. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/w54nN.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w54nN.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlsIr.jpg)[image]

Comment: Is this a "pool wall"? You shall take a full view/wild angle shot of the structure and its surrounding, your wording is confusing, and the photo does not help.

Comment: Sorry, I added a pic. You should be able to get a better understanding by looking at the backside. It completely surrounds the inground pool area.

Comment: A couple of longer shots are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, jack up the thing sitting on top, fix the mortar joints. Move the cinder blocks back into alignment. Might could secure a rope or chain if needed... and use a double or quad pully system to pull the blocks back into alignment. (Each additional loop haves the total weight- so 4 is 1/4 the lbs to pull... not sure on proper terms) or use a jack like pully or you could us a vechile like a truck, or ATV/Lawn Tractor but you would need care to do it.

Once re aligned
Rent a hammer drill, bore some 1/2" or 5/8" holes, thru one cinder block into the other.
Purchase rebar in short lengths. Place in hole cement glue, this makes the cinder blocks one piece rather then 10 pieces. They then will move as a unit one you secure them together.

The foundation ones should have rebar inside them going vertical.

These are some ideas.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ty. Do you suggest adding anything underneath this section? Gravel maybe?

Comment: I think it would depend on your situation. New gravel may not be easily compacted. Then you would be back at square one. But something I have done is put in french drains. And adjacent dry well would let the water move. 

Remember 2000 csf of surface (like a roof, or drive) - with a 1" rain is 27,000 gallons ... that is a lot of water.

Comment: We were planning on routing the gutter away from wall. My thought though are since it is leaning probably 2 inches from it's original position, it probably lacks some substrate on that side due to erosion.